# Transfer email and contacts from MSN to Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-account, outlook.com

I've been with msn.com for a while and have also had a Google account for a while, though I never decided to set up my Google account for Gmail. I've finally decided to set up Gmail and am now attempting to import my email and contacts from my MSN account (Yes, I am aware MSN uses Outlook, but my email address is specifically signed as example@msn.com, not Outlook or Hotmail; not sure if that'll make any difference).

I've followed the on-screen instructions, going into Settings, clicking "Account and Import", clicking "Import mail and contacts" and the typical step 1 window pops up:

[image: Step 1 window]

So I enter my old MSN address (example@msn.com), and then THIS pops up:

[image: Step 1...What?]

Alright, so I need to log into my MSN account and confirm the import, and... 
therein lies the problem. I don't know what they  mean by "confirm the import", and other than the email that informs me I have a Gmail account now (which has no confirmation link on it, I might add), I'm not given any information on how to do this.

So, how the heck do I "Confirm the import"?